# A Boy Named Sue - Copyright?

Tags: creative-writing

I am the agent for a writer who has written a screenplay adaptation of the story of the poem, "A Boy Named Sue," which is the name of the screenplay story.  What copyright clearance is needed or is this necessary for a screenplay adaptation?

Comment: I would ask this on the https://law.stackexchange.com site.

Answer (score 2):

Any adaptation of a copyrighted work requires permission to be published. That permission needs to be in the form of a license.

A screenplay is not usually published, but a movie made from a screenplay is. The publisher of the movie will need to purchase the movie rights (a kind of license) from the estate of [Mr Silverstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shel_Silverstein), the author of the poem.

It’s not impossible to shop a script to movie studios without already having the movie rights. The movie studio may or may not be interested, as the lack of license will mean buying the screenplay will require more work and risk than a wholly original story. If they are interested though, the movie studio is capable of pursuing a licensing deal.

Of course, Mr Silverstein’s estate is not guaranteed to offer a license to anyone.